# Returning list.append() throws "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)" in recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to write a recursive function to return the longest increasing subsequence, but error occur says "`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`"

```
def helper(cur_seq, seq, cur_i, result):
    if len(seq) == cur_i:
        return result.append(cur_seq)
    else:
        next_i = cur_i + 1
        if len(cur_seq) == 0 or seq[cur_i] > cur_seq[-1]:
            temp = cur_seq.copy()
            temp1 = cur_seq.copy()
            temp.append(seq[cur_i])
            return helper(temp, seq, next_i, result) + helper(temp1, seq, next_i, result)
        else:
            return helper(cur_seq.copy(), seq, next_i, result)


def longest_sub_sequence(seq):
    cur_seq = []

    result = helper(cur_seq, seq, 0, [])

    max_length = 0
    for i in result:
        if len(i) > max_length:
            max_length = len(i)


    return max_length


if __name__ == "__main__":

    seq = [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]
    y = longest_sub_sequence(seq)
    print(y)
```

Comment: Relevant: [Appending turns my list to NoneType](//stackoverflow.com/q/3840784)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.append` is an in-place operation. For example,

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
result = l.append(4)

print(result)
# None

print(l)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`append` returns `None`, modifying `l` in-place. This means that `return result.append(cur_seq)` in your function will return `None`, and the two recursive calls result in `None + None` which gives you the `TypeError`.

The fix would be to append *first*, return *later*.

```
def helper(cur_seq, seq, cur_i, result):
    if len(seq) == cur_i:
        result.append(cur_seq)
        return result
    ...
```